# Call Microsoft EWS from JSF app running on JBoss

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

I'm running JBoss 4.2.3, Java 1.5, and Ubuntu. Before you tell me to post on the JBossWS forum, I already have and there is not a lot of activity over there. I am trying to call a Microsoft Exchange web service end point from a JSF web application. I have written other web service end points and have successfully built clients into my web application. I also use the same code for this client in a stand alone Java application to call the exchange web service and everything works great, but for some reason I am getting this exception in my web app:

```
org.jboss.ws.WSException: Cannot uniquely indentify operation: {http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchang
e/services/2006/messages}Subscribe
```

The exception is thrown when the com.microsoft.schemas.exchange.services._2006.messages.ExchangeServicePortType subscribe method is called. Relevent part of the exception output:

```
13:17:15,718 ERROR [STDERR] org.jboss.ws.WSException: Cannot uniquely indentify operation: {http://s
chemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages}Subscribe
13:17:15,719 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.getOperation(EndpointMet
aData.java:417)
13:17:15,719 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.getOperationMetaData(CommonClient.jav
a:195)
13:17:15,719 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.getOperationMetaData(CommonClient.jav
a:184)
13:17:15,719 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:309
)
13:17:15,719 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:1
72)
13:17:15,719 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:1
52)
13:17:15,719 ERROR [STDERR]     at $Proxy101.subscribe(Unknown Source)
```

There is also is a bunch of output when the javax.xml.ws.Service object is created:

```
13:17:13,438 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'The "xml:" Namespace'.
13:17:13,438 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'The "xml:" Namespace'.
13:17:13,438 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'This Version:'.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'April 19, 2006'.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Description'.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'The namespace whose name is'.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'is bound by definition to'.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'the prefix '.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'xml:'.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'according to  '.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Namespaces in XML,'.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'W3C Recommendation 14 Jan 1999'.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '(and by '.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Namespaces in XML 1.1'.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw ').'.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Note that unlike all other XML namespaces, both t
he name '.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'and'.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'the prefix are specified; '.
13:17:13,439 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'i.e., if you want XML 1.0 processors to recognize
 this namespace, you must use'.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'the reserved prefix '.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'xml:'.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '.'.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'xml:lang'.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'and '.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'xml:space'.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'As of the last update of this document, the '.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'XML 1.0 (Third Edition) Specification'.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '(and also the '.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'XML 1.1 Specification'.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw ')'.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'defines two attribute names in this namespace:'.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'xml:lang'.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Designed for identifying'.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'the human language used in the scope of the eleme
nt to which it's'.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'attached.'.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'xml:space'.
13:17:13,440 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Designed to express whether or not the document's
 creator wishes white'.
13:17:13,441 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'space to be considered as significant in the scop
e of the element to which'.
13:17:13,441 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'it's attached.'.
13:17:13,441 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'xml:base'.
13:17:13,441 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'The '.
13:17:13,441 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'XML Base specification'.
13:17:13,441 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'describes a facility, similar to that of HTML BAS
E, for defining base URIs for'.
13:17:13,441 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'parts of XML documents.'.
13:17:13,441 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'It defines a single attribute,'.
13:17:13,441 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'xml:base'.
13:17:13,441 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw ', and describes in'.
13:17:13,441 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'detail the procedure for its use in processing re
lative URI refeferences.'.
13:17:13,441 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'xml:id'.
13:17:13,441 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'The '.
13:17:13,441 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'xml:id specification'.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'defines'.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'a single attribute, '.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'xml:id'.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw ', known to be of type '.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'ID'.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'independently of any DTD or schema.'.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Namespace change policy'.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'The '.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'XML Core Working'.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Group'.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'reserves the right to'.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'bring additional names from this namespace into a
ctive use by'.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'providing definitions for them in new specificati
ons or'.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'subsequent editions of existing specifications.  
The Working'.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Group may also make modifications to the definiti
ons of the'.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'names already in use, although such changes will 
not normally'.
13:17:13,442 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'change the well-formedness or validity of existin
g documents'.
13:17:13,443 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'or significantly change their meaning.'.
13:17:13,443 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'All changes to the use of this namespace will be 
achieved by'.
13:17:13,443 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'the publication of documents governed by the W3C 
Process.'.
13:17:13,443 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Related Resources'.
13:17:13,443 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Section'.
13:17:13,443 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '2.10'.
13:17:13,443 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'of the XML 1.0 specification describes the syntax
 and semantics of'.
13:17:13,443 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'the '.
13:17:13,443 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'xml:space'.
13:17:13,443 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'attribute.'.
13:17:13,443 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Section'.
13:17:13,443 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '2.12'.
13:17:13,443 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'of the XML 1.0 specification describes the syntax
 and semantics of'.
13:17:13,443 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'the '.
13:17:13,443 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'xml:lang'.
13:17:13,443 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'attribute.'.
13:17:13,444 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'An '.
13:17:13,444 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'XML Schema'.
13:17:13,444 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'fragment'.
13:17:13,444 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'is available which constrains the syntax of '.
13:17:13,444 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'xml:lang'.
13:17:13,444 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw ', '.
13:17:13,444 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'xml:space'.
13:17:13,444 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw ','.
13:17:13,444 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'xml:base'.
13:17:13,444 ERROR [JBossXSErrorHandler] [domain:http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-schema-1]::[key=s4s-elt-ch
aracter]::Message=s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements ot
her than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'and '.
13:17:13,444
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually easier to solve than this. I'm using jboss 4.2.3 with java 1.6. All you need to do is delete the jar files  jboss-jaxws.jar and jboss-jaxws-ext.jar from jboss/server/<>/lib, <> is probably default. This functionality is contained in the jdk now, and the older version in jboss should be tossed.

I just discovered another pair of jar files in the jboss-4.2.3.GA/lib/endorsed/ directory. Make sure you toss them too.

Update 2/25/2011
I am now using JBoss 5.1. The jar files to remove in this version are jbossws-native-jaxws-ext.jar and jbossws-native-jaxws.jar.

Comment: I havn't been able to test this yet, but I'll let you know when i do.

Comment: I remove all the *native* web services jars in the default/lib directory and everything worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to be a fairly common problem with Microsoft web services, in that the operations defined in the WSDL often share Message types. This, I believe, is not permitted by the WSDL specification, in that each operation's message payload must have a uniquely identifiable type. JBoss-WS would seem to be relying on this compliance (not unreasonably), but that's not much comfort to you.

As is often the case with Java WS client questions, I suggest not using JBoss-WS and using [Spring-WS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/client.html) instead. It ignores the WSDL and just send SOAP-wrapped XML documents. I've used Spring-WS to integrate with Microsoft web services that have exactly this "non-unique operation" problem, but I've never managed to get a traditional WSDL-binding client to work in cases like these.

Answer (score 0):

It may mean, that you have 2 or more web methods with the same `@WebParam` name. 
For ex: I noticed the error when I had, in a webservice, two web methods as below:

```
public String deleteRecords(@WebParam(name="recordsMessage") String fddXml) ; 
public String reprocessRecords(@WebParam(name="recordsMessage") String fddXml);
```